# How do I sample text from my LSTM model if the sequence length is greater than 1?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to sample text from my LSTM model, using `model.predict(...)`. My model has a sequence length of 3. This is not a problem in the context of training, where I take the first `sequence_length` tokens to input into my model.

However, in the context of sampling/generating text, I also require `sequence_length` tokens to predict the next token.

I have made it so at the start of the generated tokens there is always a token indicating the start of a sentence. This would solve the problem if my model was a vanilla RNN rather than LSTM, since vanilla RNN predicts current token based only on the previous token, not previous token**s**). In a vanilla RNN, by appending a start token to all inputs it can serve as the previous token on the first iteration.

**What I have researched/tried:**

- The implementation of a vanilla RNN [here](https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086) is able to sample text, however due to the limitation above I mentioned in the previous  can't apply its sampling method to LSTM.
- I have tried calling `model.predict(...)` with an input array less than `sequence_length`. Like I expected, `model.predict(...)` requires the input array length to be equivalent to `sequence_length`.

**How can I allow my model to sample data given less previous tokens than it requires at the beginning of my sampling, where there is not enough previous tokens to feed into the model?**

Comment: I might be disingenuous here, but if have a true requirement to sample starting from the first character and you want to use a sequence_length > 1 (which you probably do), why don't you start with three "start" tokens instead of just one? Admittedly this will waste some of the LSTM power on useless stuff (remembering how many tokens it has seen so far), but the alternative is to train it always on one problem (given at least 2 characters of "true text" predict the next) to use it on a different one (predict the first and second characters), which is IMHO worse.

Comment: Actually, maybe I was disingenuous after all. Looking at the implementation of char-rnn here https://github.com/ekzhang/char-rnn-keras it seems to me that you don't really need more than one character as the header to predict, so I don't see why you seem to make a distinction between vanilla RNN and LSTM on this point.